# Assigning variable in powershell and passing to commands

Tags: variables, powershell

I'm trying to leverage the `get-mailboxfolderstatistics` commandlet to obtain the item counts for certain inbox folders for a list of users within a distribution list.

I've used the `get-distributiongroupmember` commandlet filtering just the "Name" and assigned that to a variable.

Here is where I need some help and perhaps there is a simpler method, I want to pass each of the user names to the "identity" parameter of the `get-mailboxfolderstats` command so the script will for each of the users in a given distribution group provide me the folder stats I desire.

Thank you for reading and your help.

So far I have:

```
$s = get-distributiongroupmember -identity 23rdFloor | Select Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Piping the result to the foreach command should work;

> $s =  get-distributiongroupmember -identity 23rdFloor | Select Name
>   $s | ForEach-Object {get-mailboxfolderstatistics -identity $_.Name }

http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/2010/02/exchange-management-shell-error-pipelines-cannot-be-executed-concurrently/

Comment: Thanks it worked somewhat, i am getting results but it's generating the following error along with skipping some members of the group..the error is "Pipeline not executed because a pipeline is already executing. Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently"

Comment: @Percy - I've put it back into two steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the group members directly to Get-MailboxFolderStatistics:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember 23rdFloor |
Where-Object {$_.RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox'} | 
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics
```